# “Come (straight) to the point” versus “Get (straight) to the point”

Tags: meaning

I was told that these two expressions mean the same thing, but I’m not sure about that. Is my usage correct in both of these examples?  Is their meaning roughly equivalent?

> I’ll **get** (straight) to the point: you need to chill out first.
>
> I’ll **come** (straight) to the point: you must not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're fine. And they mean the same thing.

Both use a [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) of conversation as movement from one point to another; in this sense they're the same as

- *I'll come to the party tonight.*
- *I'll get to the party tonight.*

both of which mean that I will attend the party tonight, at some point; *get to* means *arrive at* in this sense, not far distant from its normal inchoative sense of *come to be*.

Comment: Hmm, so could they also be used in this sense?                                                         "I wish you'd get to the point" and "I wish you'd come to the point"

Comment: Yup. Pretty much interchangeable; there are probably some contexts where one might have an invited inference (like _I'll get to it_ may mean it will take a while).